# Same value for all columns fields yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have gridview with some columns. I want to create one colums like

```
'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ['header' =>  'Manager',
        //'value' => 'first'],
```

Column name is Manager and all fields equels 'first'? How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on info provided, this is easy to achieve with custom grid column:

```
<?php

namespace app\components;    

class CommonValueColumn extends Column
{
    public $commonValue = 'Default value for common value';    

    protected function renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index)
    {
        return $commonValue;
    }
}
```

Then use it in `GridView` widget like this:

```
'columns' => [
    // ...
    [
        'class' => 'app\components\CommonValueColumn',
        'header' => 'Manager',
        'commonValue' => 'First',
    ],
    // ...
],
```

Note that if the `manager` is a model attribute and the value needs to be taken from database, this is a wrong way to do it.

Information about GridView widget is available in the [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#gridview).

Comment: I couldnt find class class CommonValueColumn in advanced template

Comment: @cruim There is no such class neither in Yii2 core nor in advanced template. You should create it by yourself. I provided implementation example.

Comment: I add this `[
            'header' => 'Manager',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->name; // $data['name'] for array data, e.g. using SqlDataProvider.
            },
        ],`And create `name` in model.

Comment: As I said, if you are working with values from database (even without models), this is a wrong way to do it. Check the documentation link I provided.